# Vite include .ts file in tsconfig.json and tsconfig.node.json

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite, tsconfig

I have a Vite + Vue project with a pretty standard tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "vite/client"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src"],
      "@comp/*": ["./src/components"],
      "@styl/*": ["./src/styles"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "stories/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

and tsconfig.node.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Inside of src, I have a utils directory: `src/utils/example.ts`

I'm building the project as a library with Vite, so I have an index.ts file that includes `export { ... } from './utils/example'`.

However, I also use some of that utility typescript in vite.config.ts: `import { ... } from './src/utils/example'` and then use it in `defineConfig`.

However, I get this error when I import in vite.config.ts:
`File '.../src/utils/example.ts' is not listed within the file list of project '.../tsconfig.node.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern. ts(6307)`

I've had a similar issue in the past, and solved it by adding `"src/utils/example.ts"` to `"include": [...]` in `tsconfig.node.json`.

While adding this makes that error go away, I then get this error in `index.ts` when importing: `Output file '.../src/utils/examples.d.ts' has not been built from source file '.../src/utils/example.ts'. ts(6305)`.

Note that the project seems to build and run just fine despite this, and I'm wondering if it's an IDE issue? I'm using VS Code with Volar.